# How can I replace an EXE's icon to the "default" icon?

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I converted a python script to an exe using pyinstaller. I want to know how I can change the icon it gave me to the default icon. In case you don't know what I mean, look at C:\Windows\System32\alg.exe. There are many more files with that icon, but that is one of them. Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this, and let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Have you tried `pyinstaller -i`?

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the icon from the EXE using resource editor like this one: http://www.resedit.net/

Then, Windows will display its default icon, used for EXEs that don't have one (usually programs without GUI).

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to extract the icon from the exe, and set that as the icon file with `pyinstaller -i extracted.ico myscript.py`. You can extract the icon with tools available online or you can use `pywin32` to extract the icons.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest to use `auto-py-to-exe` module for conversion of python script to exe. At first install using command `pip install auto-py-to-exe` after that run it through python command line just by typing `auto-py-to-exe`, you'll get an window where you'll get the icon option.

Please vote if you find your solution.